# How can we toggle between two tables in Pinescript using a single boolean value?

Tags: debugging, frontend, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to toggle between two tables like this in Pinescript v5:

```js
// live table
var table LEV_Display_mini = table.new(position.bottom_right, 14, 3)
var table LEV_Display = table.new(position.bottom_right, 14, 5)

color op_val_col = lev_sustain == max_lev ? color.green : lev_sustain >= lev_sustain[1] ? color.yellow : color.red

if barstate.islast
    if not miniOn
    
        table.cell(LEV_Display, 0, 0, 'New Positions:', text_color=color.white, text_size=size.auto, bgcolor=color.black)
        table.cell(LEV_Display, 1, 0, str.format('{0}x', max_lev), text_color=color.white, text_size=size.auto, bgcolor=color.black)
        
        table.cell(LEV_Display, 0, 1, 'Valid For:', text_color=color.white, text_size=size.auto, bgcolor=color.black)
        table.cell(LEV_Display, 1, 1, str.format('{0} bars', tradelength), text_color=color.white, text_size=size.auto, bgcolor=color.black)
        
        table.cell(LEV_Display, 0, 2, 'Est. Liq. Price:', text_color=color.white, text_size=size.auto, bgcolor=color.black)
        table.cell(LEV_Display, 1, 2, str.format('{0} L | {1} S', math.round(long_liq,decim),math.round(short_liq,decim)), text_color=color.white, text_size=size.auto, bgcolor=color.black)
        
        table.cell(LEV_Display, 0, 3, 'Open Positions:', text_color=color.yellow, text_size=size.auto, bgcolor=color.black)
        table.cell(LEV_Display, 1, 3, str.format('{0}x', lev_sustain), text_color = op_val_col, text_size=size.auto, bgcolor=color.black)
        
        table.cell(LEV_Display, 0, 4, 'Est. Liq. Price:', text_color=color.yellow, text_size=size.auto, bgcolor=color.black)
        table.cell(LEV_Display, 1, 4, str.format('{0} L | {1} S', math.round(op_long_liq,decim),math.round(op_short_liq,decim)), text_color=color.white, text_size=size.auto, bgcolor=color.black)
    
    else if miniOn
        
        table.cell(LEV_Display_mini, 0, 0, 'New Positions:', text_color=color.white, text_size=size.auto, bgcolor=color.black)
        table.cell(LEV_Display_mini, 1, 0, str.format('{0}x', max_lev), text_color=color.white, text_size=size.auto, bgcolor=color.black)
        
        table.cell(LEV_Display_mini, 0, 1, 'Est. Liq. Price:', text_color=color.white, text_size=size.auto, bgcolor=color.black)
        table.cell(LEV_Display_mini, 1, 1, str.format('{0} L | {1} S', math.round(long_liq,decim),math.round(short_liq,decim)), text_color=color.white, text_size=size.auto, bgcolor=color.black)
        
        table.cell(LEV_Display_mini, 0, 2, 'Open Positions:', text_color=color.yellow, text_size=size.auto, bgcolor=color.black)
        table.cell(LEV_Display_mini, 1, 2, str.format('{0}x', lev_sustain), text_color = op_val_col, text_size=size.auto, bgcolor=color.black)
```

Currently the result of this is the table object `LEV_Display` is showing when `miniOn` is false, and not showing when `miniOn` is true. This is fine.

The bug is that the table object `LEV_Display_mini` never shows regardless of that boolean value.
At first I thought this may be some kind of overlapping graphics, but alas changing `LEV_Display_mini`'s position elsewhere made no difference. I even tried deleting and clearing the table opposite of the one that should show and that also did not help.

Essentially I need a single boolean value that will result in table-A hiding and table-B showing and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one table in one chart position, so when you create the `LEV_Display` table with `table.new()`, it overwrites the `LEV_Display_mini` created before it. Attempts to fill cells in the `LEV_Display_mini` table lead to nothing because it has been replaced and thus does not exist.

The easy fix is to just get rid of the `LEV_Display_mini` table. You can create a single table and fill it with either full info or short info depending on your bool input. The cells that are not filled are not displayed, so even though your full table created with 5 rows, it will only have 3 rows visually as long as you will not fill the remaining rows.